# nginx (last/break) rewrites

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a simple nginx rewrite here, using ***permanent*** flag, it works fine.

```
location /area1/ {
rewrite /area1/(.*)$ / permanent;
}
```

However i want to retain the initial url, which seems from research to just need the ***last*** or ***break*** flag instead.

```
location /area1/ {
rewrite /area1/(.*)$ / break;
}
```

After changing permanent for ***break*** (or ***last***) , it just seems to ignore the redirect entirely.

Please can someone demonstrate a working internal redirect that retains the initial url - i know this should be simple but i have tried a ton of config variations around the above and nothing seems to work, redirect was more complex to start with but i have reduced it to its basic form just to get the syntax correct , and i'm still failing...

Among many pages i referenced, this is one - https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

```
server {
    listen        80;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/root_host.access.log  main;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/root_host.error.log;

    location /area1/ {
        rewrite /area1/(.*)$ / break;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is not working? What happened instead? You also need to show the _entire_ `server` block.

Comment: thanks, I have added the server block now. 

the problem is it does nothing, it shows the page i would see if the rewrite was not there at all.

If it is exactly the same but with the permanent flag instead it redirects to the page fine, i just cant get it to redirect the content from / while keeping the url as /area1/

Comment: Instead of rewrite you can "return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;"

Comment: that's just a redirect though, like i am getting with the permenant flag.

its the server side rewrite i'm struggling to get working , i need the url to not follow the redirection

Comment: Do you mean you want to proxy the request to another server and return the response to the browser, rather than redirect the browser to a new URL? If so that's not the question you asked, possibly because you don't know the appropriate language. If that's what you want look into proxy_pass, documentation is excellent and there are dozens of tutorials that will show you how to use it.

Comment: sorry no that's not what i want, the location i wish to rewrite to is on the same server.

see the link i posted above , to nginx blog, the final example on the page is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: Im just trying to redirect one path to another on a single server, while retaining the initial path in the browser so the actual path isnt seen.  if this is not the correct approach , what is ?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to give a definitive answer. Is that path a server with a web interface? Is it a file on the file system? proxy_pass or try_files is likely to be the answer. Please edit your question to make things more clear.

Comment: It is a web server, but the paths are not folders(its just wordpress). From the response it seems this must be the wrong approach as the idea is pretty simple and this seem edto be the way this was done when i search for the solution e.g. https://goo.gl/fp1Ebf or https://goo.gl/GYxZMf. I will look into and experiment with try_files / proxy_pass today.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rewrite ... last` doesn't really do anything.

You internally rewrite `/area1/` to `/` which is then internally rewritten to `/index.php` by the last `try_files` statement.

Without the `location /area1/` block present, `/area1/` is internally rewritten to `/index.php` by the last `try_files` statement.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, excluding that line did have an effect - the page redirected with last/break, but the browser didn't retain the original url, it followed the redirect. I do actually need to keep that config, so something i'll need to work around.